# In Ramayan, where is it mentioned that Atikaya held the trident of Lord Shiva?

Tags: shiva, ramayana, valmiki, kailasa

There is a story that says that once Atikaya went to Kailash and for some reason Lord Shiva got angry and he released his powerful trident on Atikaya.

However, Atikaya caught hold of the trident and also respected Lord Shiva.

Therefore he was blessed with all kinds of divine weapons.

My question is:

what is the source of this story?

I am not able to find this either in Valmiki Ramayan or in Ramcharitmanas.

Exactly in which version of Ramayan this incident is mentioned and is this story authentic or not?